# React - Suspense not fully loaded scss

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, code-splitting

I did the following implementation:

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from 'react'
```

1. Load (lazy) my component:

   `const Component = lazy(() => import('./componentPath'))`
2. Wrap the Switch in Suspense:

   ```
   <Suspense fallback={<span>Loading...</span>}>
       <Switch>
           <Route exact path='/path' component={Component} //>
       </Switch>
   </Suspense>
   ```

and I hit the following issue:

On many places **css** is with **bad margins, padding even there are some styles which are missing**.

My goal is to lazy load components on Route level.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thank you in advance.

**Components structure:**

Main component which is lazy loaded on **router** level:

```
import React from 'react';
import FirstSubComp;

import './style.scss'

const MainComp = () => (

    return (
      <FIrstSubComp/>
   )
);
```

First SubComp:

```
import React from 'react'
import './style.scss'

const FIrstSubComp = () => (

    return (
      <div>First sub comp<div>
   )
);
```

Comment: Where are you importing your CSS?

Comment: Well the scss for each component is imported in their component directory, same for subcomponents they have own import on scss

Comment: Please post the import code

Comment: updated code structure

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who encounters this problem, make sure that every component imports its `.css` files.

I had some components that depend on `.css` files of other components (not parents), which caused this issue.